# Wcf Service Failed to found the End Point on Local Host

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis

I am consuming the wcf Rest Service into Angular JS Application . I created several methods to perform the operation. First I have the wcf service with class library project and i created another wcf service project to host it in local IIS.
When i run the wcf service on local host its works fine but the problem is with the url when i typed the method name its throws exceptions that the End point not found . For example   http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/GetCustomers// Error the end point not found .

Here is my interface..

```
  [OperationContract]

        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/GetCustomers")]
        string GetCustomers(string prefix);

        [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       UriTemplate = "/GetAccountDetails")]
        bool GetAccountDetails(string Account_Number);
```

Here is app.cong file in class library project .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCS" connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=HalifaxDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="HalifaxDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=;initial catalog=HalifaxDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="HalifaxWCFProject.HalifaxService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="HalifaxWCFProject.IHalifaxService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/HalifaxWCFProject/HalifaxService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Here is service.svc code for IIS  .

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="HalifaxWCFProject.HalifaxService"%>
```

Here is the web.config for .svc file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCS" connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=HalifaxDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="HalifaxDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=;initial catalog=HalifaxDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="HalifaxWCFProject.HalifaxService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" behaviorConfiguration="REST" contract="HalifaxWCFProject.IHalifaxService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="REST">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Here is the screen shot .
[image: click here to see the result]
I have defined the end point in web.config file . I am wondering i got this error the End point not Found .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive the "endpoint not found" error because you've defined HTTP *Post* endpoints.  Therefore, you cannot test them in a web browser since it sends an HTTP *Get* request.

If you wish the test your service without writing any code, use [Fiddler's](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) Composer feature to send an HTTP Post request.

[Fiddler Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9je6x.png)

Or change the WebInvoke attribute to allow an HTTP Get request.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  UriTemplate = "/GetCustomers")]
```

Comment: What is the changes I have to make for accessing  the get request as well

Comment: I've amended my answer to explain how to enable a web browser to test your service method.